# In ConTeXt, how do I vertically align frames on the bottom line of text in each frame?

Tags: context, context-lmtx

Using ConTeXt, I am trying to align the text in two `\framed` boxes vertically. I am hoping that the bottom text line of the first `\framed` aligns perfectly with the bottom text line of the second `\framed` such that it appears to be a single line of text. Please note that the contents of the first `\framed` will span more than one line.

Here is an MWE that demonstrates the unwanted behavior:

```
\starttext

Test
\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=depth]{Testing, 2022}%
\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=depth]{89}
Test

\stoptext
```

[image: Output of MWE]

The text that I want aligned as if they were printed in a single line is "2002" and "89". The other text (e.g., "Test", "Testing", "Test") need not be aligned.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need `location=bottom` but LMTX has a bug in the `\framed` code and omits the final `\strut` at the end of the box content.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem altogether. 

Here's the solution/work-around for the bug and results in the text aligning properly:

`\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=bottom]{Testing, 2022\strut}\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=bottom]{89\strut}`


@WolfgangSchuster : If you put this in an answer, I'm happy to accept it!

Comment: There was a new release today which fixed the bug with the missing `\strut` in LMTX.

Comment: In addition to what @WolfgangSchuster writes, there is now also a `location=inline` to try out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution (after a bug fix to add a missing `\strut` in LMTX):

```
\starttext

Test
\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=bottom]{Testing, 2022}%
\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=bottom]{89}
Test

\stoptext
```

[image: Image of output]

If using older versions of LMTX, it is necessary to include an additional `\strut` to each command:

```
\starttext

Test
\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=bottom]{Testing, 2022\strut}%
\framed[width=0.5in,align=flushleft,location=bottom]{89\strut}
Test

\stoptext
```

Many thanks to @WolfgangSchuster for the solution!